I use kafka connectct to create two topics to transfer data to each other, but it seems that messages are piled up in the topics
first step http://192.168.245.128:8083/connector-plugins
Shows
[{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"10.0.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect .jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"10.0.1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","type":"sink ","version":"2.4.0"},{"class":"org.apache

.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"2.4.0"} ,{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect .mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","type":"source", "version":"1"}

Step 2I created the library kafka and a table user in MySQL(192.168.245.128)
Step 3 I requested
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'http://192.168.245.128:8083/connectors' \\ --data \\ '{"name":"songshu-upload-mysql","config":{ "connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector", "connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://192.168.245.128:3306/kafka?user=root&password=Yhf_1018", "table.whitelist":"user", "incrementing.column.name": "id", "mode":"incrementing", "topic.prefix": "songshu-mysql-"}}'

in 192.168.245.129 and it shows
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Date: Tue, 07 May 2024 08:24:09 GMT
Location: http://192.168.245.128:8083/connectors/songshu-upload-mysql
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 363
Server: Jetty(9.4.20.v20190813)

{"name":"songshu-upload-mysql","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://192.168.245.128:3306/kafka?user=root&password=Yhf_1018","table.white\`

Step 4
insert into user values (1,'aaa',18); insert into user values (2,'bbb',10);
Step 5
I requested
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.245.128:9092 --topic songshu-mysql-user --from-beginning

but it nothing
it cannot display the data inserted into the table
I don’t know how to configure connect-distributed.properties in cluster mode.In bootstrap.servers here, do you need to fill in the current IP, or should you put the entire cluster’s IP?
# A list of host/port pairs to use for establishing the initial connection to the Kafka cluster.
bootstrap.servers=192.168.245.129:9092
#,192.168.245.129:9092,192.168.245.130:9092

# unique name for the cluster, used in forming the Connect cluster group. Note that this must not conflict with consumer group IDs
group.id=connect-cluster

# The converters specify the format of data in Kafka and how to translate it into Connect data. Every Connect user will
# need to configure these based on the format they want their data in when loaded from or stored into Kafka
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
# Converter-specific settings can be passed in by prefixing the Converter's setting with the converter we want to apply
# it to
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

I changed bootstrap.servers to the IP of the current host in both master and slave1, but it will always be displayed after startup.
[2024-05-08 09:34:42,414] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-connect-cluster-1, groupId=connect-cluster] 12 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [connect-offsets-5, connect-offsets-15, connect-offsets-9, connect-offsets-11, connect-offsets-17, connect-offsets-3, connect-offsets-23, connect-offsets-13, connect-offsets-19, connect-offsets-1] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:1056)


Look at the logs or the /status endpoint of the connector for the any errors
